# Version control branching strategies - medium sized team and frequent releases

Tags: tfs, version-control, agile, azure-devops, tfvc

We are a medium sized team of 10 developers (3 developers per project) and want to know which versioning strategy would be optimal.

Have already done significant research into this and found that a *"Branch on release"* makes sense. However, we implemented this before and found that it come with significant overhead as we released every second week.

One pattern that is barely mentioned is branching on demand with labeling. The way it works is that you label and take a snapshot of your code on every release to be tested and published from. Then only branch if there is a bug that needs to be fixed in production.

I have drawn up a diagram that illustrates this approach, that also incorporates branch on feature for features that span multiple sprints. 
[image]

On each check-in, the code is shelved for code analysis, build successful and code reviews before being included in the trunk branch.

Are there any drawbacks that I am not aware of? Why isn't this approach more widespread?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any major problems with that approach.

I would recommend doing regular merges from the trunk to branches to stop them diverging too far from the trunk code. This is particularly important on long lived branches.

It is possible to automate this using continuous integration, say by scheduling a merge every night that fails if the merge creates conflicts. This will avoid a nasty merge at the end when you collapse the branch back in to the trunk.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the main disadvantage to using labels in such a manner in TFS is that labels are not versioned.  If one person deletes/changes the label there is no way to get it back unless you keep a copy/backup of the label.  If you do follow this please keep a record of contents of the label so it can be recreated if necessary.